# Locate object based on shape

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, shapes, object-detection

I want to locate a certain object within an image using Matlab.

This object always has the exactly same shape, only the color differs:

[image: Object I want to locate within an image]

I tried with object detection algorithms based on point features, but these algorithms does not work since there are not enough features within this object image.

Is there a way to locate this object in my images, given that there 1 instance of this object within every image, for example by it's unique shape?
The scale of this object can change and might not be colored green completely (partly grey).

An example of an image within I want to locate the spiral is:

[image: Image to locate the spiral in]

Comment: Does the scale of the object change as well, or is it guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: @rayryeng the scale of the object can change

Comment: What about orientation?  Will that be different as well?  For example, will you see this object rotated at, say, a 45 degree angle?

Comment: @rayryeng No, the orientation will always be the same

Comment: Sorry for the multitude of questions.  Could you provide an example image where this object may appear?  I want to get an idea of the composition of the other objects inside this image where we also see this object.

Comment: @rayryeng I've added an image example in the original question above

Comment: Awesome thanks.  I'll fool around with it and get back to you.  My gut feeling is to perhaps do a sinusoidal curve fitting with each detected bounding box in your image and isolating the box that fits this model the best.

Comment: Does the object always appear over a black background like shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Phase Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation) of the image with the template.
Below is the algorithm:

1. Convert both template and the image to the gray scale
2. Compute the 2DFT of the template after removing the mean and zero-padding it to image size
3. Compute the 2DFT of the image after removing the mean
4. Multiply the 2DFT of the image with the conjugate of the 2DFT of the template
5. Divide out the magnitudes of the 2DFT of both the image and the template (leaving behind the phase)
6. Take the Inverse 2DFT and find the peaks in the real part

Code below implements the algorithm:

```
%% Load video frames and template
imageFile = 'image.png';
templateFile = 'template.png';
imageColor = imread(imageFile);
image = im2double( rgb2gray( imageColor ) );
template = im2double( rgb2gray( imread(templateFile) ));

[hI, wI] = size(image);
[hT, wT] = size(template);

%% Perform frequency domain correlation
templateDFT = fft2((template - mean2(template))/std2(template), hI, wI);
templateDFTMag = abs(templateDFT);

templateFilter = conj(templateDFT) ./ templateDFTMag;

imageDFT = fft2((image - mean2(image))/std2(image) );
imageDFTMag = abs(imageDFT);
corrDFT = imageDFT .* templateFilter ./ imageDFTMag;
corr = real(ifft2(corrDFT));

%% Detect peak and plot
[maxCorr, maxIdx] = max(corr(:));
[maxRow, maxCol] = ind2sub([hI wI], maxIdx);

figure; imshow(imageColor); hold on; 
rectangle('Position', [maxCol-wT/2, maxRow-hT/2, wT, hT], 'EdgeColor', 'y');
```

Below is what I get:

[image]

Caveats:

- This scheme is not very robust to large scale variation or rotation. However, small scale variation will be tolerated.